# Utility classes: static class vs member variable vs local variable

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm creating a utility class `CommonDaoOperations` that contains several generic methods: `Create`, `Update`, `Delete`. 
This is not a base class because some DAOs are more complex and can't use these generic methods, but many DAOs can.

I'm now pondering how that utiliy class should look like exactly:

- static class with only static generic methods
- regular class with generic methods, created once per DAO as private readonly member
- regular class with generic methods, created once per DAO method (in each call)

Creating an instance of a class per DAO / method obviously costs more than calling a static method, but I'm pretty sure that these costs are negligable in almost any application.

I'd favor solution 2 or 3 because of the benefits of non-static classes (interfaces, can be mocked, can be derived / enhanced, could gather parameters via constructor in the future should it be necessary (compared to a 10-parameter-method in a static class)).

So I guess the real question is: should I be creating my utility class as a member variable, or instantiate it per DAO method?

```
public void Create(User user) { 
   new CommonDaoOperations().Create(user);
}
public void Delete(User user) {
   var daoOps = new CommonDaoOperations();
   daoOps.CheckSomething(); // just an example of multiple calls to the class
   daoOps.Delete(user);
}
```

I'm interested to hear what other devs think about any of these approaches, or if there's still anothere / better way to do this.

**Edit**

Just realized that I should have given approach #3 more thought - as Vadim pointed out, replacing the concrete class would be cumbersome when it's instantiated in each method, but I could factor that in a property:

```
private CommonDaoOperations DaoOps {
    get { return new CommonDaoOperations(); }
}
public void Create(User user) {
   DaoOps.Create(user);
}
```

I believe this to be more maintianable than the above snippet, however know I introduced a property for a 'utility' class in my DAO, which might be a code smell by itself (as Ant P pointed out).

**Summary**

This was a tough decision - while I accepted the answer from Ant P, Vadim's answer is also legitimate. Which approach to use depends on the utility class, **all 3 approaches have their uses** (except the updated #3). At least that is my take of the provided answers.

- *Static classes* do have their uses, but also many downsides as briefly mentioned above.
- *Regular class, instantiated per method:* the utiliy class is created and used just where it is required. Reduces dependencies, keeps your type pure.
- *Regular class, instantiated as member:* when many/all methods require an instance of the utility class, it may be a better idea to create a member variable. Changing the type or how it is instantiated becomes easier this way.

Comment: Your 'utility class' should not be a member of the DAO's. `static` looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will let those more qualified comment on the performance implications; however, here are my thoughts on each:

**1. Static class**

This concept is fine for simple, 'uncomprehensive' utility methods that require no real extensibility but - as you note yourself - your common DAO operations stand to grow considerably more sophisticated. This is unlikely to be very manageable as a single static class, particularly when it's used across multiple different types of DAO.

**2. Concrete class, instantiated per-DAO object**

This is all fine and dandy, but do you really need the utility class to be a member of the individual DAO? I could understand this if you needed some kind of consistency or state persistence within the utility class, across the lifetime of the DAO, but it seems that these methods are fairly nebulous (true to its name as a "utility" class).

Which leaves **3. Concrete class, instantiated per method.** This seems the most natural solution to me. This gives you the flexibility to make use of all of the advantages of a concrete class as you acknowledge in your question, while restricting the scope of the object to where it's needed - the individual method call.

Should your class evolve into something that's needed across the entire DAO, e.g. you suddenly need to maintain the state of the object (or if you need to inject it into the DAO's constructor, or something else along those lines), you can always change where it's instantiated (though it seems to me that, if this happens, you don't really have a utility class any more and you need to reconsider how this class fits into your architecture).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Since you'd advice against #2, what are your thoughts on my updated implementation of #3? It has the same disadvantage as the member solution, however Vadim has a point in that when I have to replace the utility class I have to search for a lot of instantiations.

Comment: There's not really much point having a property and just re-instantiating the class in the DAO every time you use it - if you're going to do that, you might as well just keep it as a member variable. Concerns of having to replace it in multiple places are valid if you anticipate having to do that; however, making an effort to reduce instances of every class you write in case you end up wanting to remove it altogether seems a counterproductive approach to me.

Comment: Additionally, due to the way you seem to be looking at this, I'm beginning to wonder if this should really be a utility class rather than a generic repository or similar, where **it** manages your DAOs, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you plan to create an exceptionally large number of these objects, I don't think it'll affect performance.

I would prefer (2). There's simply need to create it for each use, that's just writing code for nothing. In addition, if you'd ever want to use some sort of IOC, get the utility class as a parameter, change the way it is initialized or simply change the class to another class - having a single member to change is a lot easier than changing all the places where it's used.

Unless you have a very good reason, stay away from statics or Singletons. (an example of a very good reason is something like developing an addon or a plugin in which you don't control the way your classes are initialized and used).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I updated my question with a different take on #3, thoughts?

Comment: 1. What's the point in creating the class each time it is used? Why not create it once and use it? This solution also does not really address the other issues I've mentioned 2. I did not address the design, just took your use of the utility class for granted. This is indeed a code smell (but there are far worse), but it's difficult to say anything more specific without knowing your code.

Comment: @1: The object only exists when and where I need it, while a member variable is created in the constructor and exists until the DAO is GCed, even if only a few methods use it (varies from DAO to DAO). Just for clarity, why would a property not address the other issues (IoC, change the way its initialized..)? Changing the type of a property vs a variable or the way either is initialized ought to have similar implications on my code.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. I prefer to create it once and reuse it, seems like less work to do, but it doesn't really matter. You are right, it does address the other issues. I was thinking about something unrelated, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When considering the difference and usages between **static classes** and **concrete classes** sure there are implications to take in mind, see the testability for example (but this is not so sure at all as shown after), but there are first of all, some assumptions to do:

- **instance classes** have state, manage state, and behaviors are related to it's internal state, if operations are not related to internal state in some ways, these are truly candidates for static methods, but I will say more after about that. This is the base even for  **encapsulation**, and goes hand by hand with **SRP** (Single Responsibility Principle) which says that a class should have a single responsibility, doing one thing and no more, so, this gives you the fact that methods are all related to it's internal state directly or indirectly
- **static classes** haven't and don't manage state. Maybe some one could say that it's not true at all, see singletons. Well, singleton's maybe good, but singletons designed as static classes are too close to anti-pattern, in this case, singletons could be managed as IoC containers does, by managing justo one **instance** at all. If needed I could provide some examples about with and without containers.

Well, someone says static classes are something close to anti-pattern, because for example testability.. well, this is non true, and this depends of what the static class and test which involves to is related. 
I will report a very good example on that by on of the great software architect at all, **Udi Dahan**, which for example, in a good article about *Domain Events*, he talks between other things, about static classes and testability, here the link [Domain Events Salvation](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) if you go to the section **How to raise domain events** and **Unit testing with domain events**, he talks about that.

After that, as you says, another difference about the two, is about memory cost, but others says about that. Take in mind that, tools like Reshaper, makes suggestions to transform instance classes/methods which doesn't handle state to the static representation, this in advantage of memory and usage.

The last words about your design: `CommonDaoOperations` seems to a truly static class which doesn't handle state, so it's a good candidate to be a **static class**, for it's nature, for jobs it does. You can instead treat it as "singleton" using a IoC container and configuring that class in the right way. There are many ways to accomplish that in other ways without Containers.. here a simple article which talks about singletons and static classes [C# Singleton, Static Class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static). Sure making a property which returns the helper is not so a good design, and a property which returns a new instance for a get operation is always a bad design, it will be justified with solid reasons...

So seeing your design and how you use the helper class, the words says by Udi in the link above describe well the solution you should implement.

Comment: Static classes sure have their uses, but I don't think any class that is stateless should be static. Take `IEqualityComparer` for example. While you could create a static class for comparing objects (no state required after all), the regular class / interface approach is immensely more powerful and flexible. The Domain Events link you provided contains an example of a legitimate static class, but this should not be used as an excuse to make every stateless class static (like the Handler type on that very site).

Comment: I Totally agree with you, in fact what I said was a general explanation. Personally I don't like much static classes.. They should be used carefully when are really needed and justified! cheers